# linux and windows 10 having issues in dual booting

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I've installed Pop OS alongside my windows 10, but now I have a problem: I have to choose which partition has to boot in my boot settings, no dual boot menu at all.
This is how I installed the pop OS:

[image: Partitions of my hard drives]

I created an EFI partition on my SSD for the Pop OS (The 512 MB) and the root in my HDD (The G:/) and I don't know what is the F:/ partition.

How can I fix this?

And I think that this might help (List of operating systems, no linux):

[image: List of operating systems, no linux]

Comment: Simplest way to do is to boot into pop is and install refind : instructions :  https://pop-planet.info/wiki/index.php?title=REFInd ; drive f seems useless to me so check if it contains any files ,if not delete it ;also seems like you have forgotten to turn off fast boot and so linux partition is shown as raw; and I think it would be better if you delete both f and efi partition you created on first drive and reinstall pop os with efi partition on second drive only

Comment: And do not expect linux to show in your list of operating system in second screenshot ; it needs to manually configured if you want windows bootloader to boot both windows and pop os

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes, I almost forgot about the fast boot, but is there a way to not turn off this thing? I had ubuntu and windows 8 at the same time in another system and the shared partition ( for transferring files between these two OSs ) was locked and was read-only in ubuntu, after disabling the fast boot, the problem has been fixed.

Comment: I will do what you just said and report anything, success or failure :)

Comment: @Madhubala sorry about the huge delay. I've tested what you said and now everything is okay, thank you again :) if you want, I can accept your answer if you write it down in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do is to boot into pop is and install refind : [instructions](https://pop-planet.info/wiki/index.php?title=REFInd) ; drive f seems useless to me so check if it contains any files ,if not delete it ;also seems like you have forgotten to turn off fast boot and so linux partition is shown as raw; and I think it would be better if you delete both f and efi partition you created on first drive and reinstall pop os with efi partition on second drive only

And do not expect linux to show in your list of operating system in second screenshot ; it needs to manually configured if you want windows bootloader to boot both windows and pop os

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed linux after windows, You can use [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to add Linux entry to the windows boot manager.

Download and install it and go to Linux/BSD tab. Set Type to Grub 2 and name Pop OS. And set Drive to automatically locate and load then click Add Entry. Now make sure windows partition is in the Boot priority #1 in BIOS/UEFI and you will get Windows boot manager will show options to boot both Windows 10 and Pop OS.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've installed that software but when it launched, it said that the EFI boot mode has some limitations, and the Linux/BSD tab contents are greyed out and cannot be changed.